# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I don't know what the problem is in my stored procedure below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetDataByColNameByTime 
`(
 IN Col_Name VARCHAR(50), 
 IN DateStart VARCHAR(50), IN DateEnd VARCHAR(50) )
 BEGIN 
 SET @sqlx = 
 CONCAT
 ('SELECT ',  Col_Name , ' ,  SAMPLE_TIME  FROM indicator_data_history I 
 WHERE ( I.SAMPLE_TIME >= `2014-04-04 11:47:57` )  
 AND ( I.SAMPLE_TIME <= `2014-04-04 11:33:57` ) 
 order by SAMPLE_TIME');
 PREPARE stmtx FROM @sqlx; 
 EXECUTE stmtx;
```

I can make a similar query work if written in a simple statement:

```
SELECT RT ,  SAMPLE_TIME  FROM indicator_data_history I WHERE ( I.SAMPLE_TIME >= '2014-04-04 11:47:57' )  AND ( I.SAMPLE_TIME <= '2014-04-04 11:33:57' ) ;
```

after analysis the quotes seem to be the problem `2014-04-04 11:33:57` - any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Backticks (`) are used for column and table names. Single quotes (') are used for strings. For example, this is invalid:

```
I.SAMPLE_TIME >= `2014-04-04 11:47:57`
```

and this is valid:

```
I.SAMPLE_TIME >= '2014-04-04 11:47:57'
```

Comment: @ D. Kasipovic, the thing is  how can you add the quote within a string because I have a syntax error by doing what you suggested

Comment: thanks D. Kasipovic for ur prompt reply u sure put me in the way of finding the solution.

Comment: @user3506769 Can you please mark the above as best answer?